# Typescript - Why is it ok to write to this readonly value? How can I prevent that?

Tags: typescript, immutability

In the following example it is possible to change the value of an object property that was declared as `readonly` without any kind of warning. I am surprised typescript has nothing against it. Do you know how I can express that in a way, so the `readonly` value stays safe?

```js
type Immutable = {
    readonly a: number;
}

type Mutable = {
    a: number;
}

function writeToA(mutable: Mutable) {
    mutable.a = 99;
    console.log(mutable);
}

const myImmutable: Immutable = {a:5};
writeToA(myImmutable) // <- How can I make sure that this gives at least a warning?
```

see this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtnArsAhgIwDbQLxQN4CwAUFKVAE4QoAmA9gHYYhQoBcU9icaE5A3MQC%20xYqEhQAssnRYouQiTJsOXHvyEiiAM0T0AxsACWDKAHdyh4BAAqtAIIAKJKkwR2Ul1gCU%20YmSjOMhAAdChyUACcEQKKpHoMAM60WMEYtADmTtKuXjHCRMTx9AnAASDwga7sFdmy8mwArIIx5pY29k7lCLUQPgD0fVAAPAC0UAAStKZQeij0sAEoANbQCYiUUMAAFiil24YJUOmGAG4Qh7tQWCglLGYo5PSG9OkA-EA)

I am wondering why typescript doesn't complain about the call `writeToA(myImmutable)` even though `myImmutable` is of type `Immutable` while the function needs a parameter of type `Mutable`.
Does typescript infer that the two types are the same because the have the same keys? Is there a way to prevent that?

Thank You!